# Show that the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$ is zero for all $n \geq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$.

I want to show that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n \ge 0$. That is, the $n$th derivative at $x=0$ is zero for all $n \ge 0$.

Any hints on how to get started? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $$f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$$

Comment: this might be a duplicate to a question posted recently, but I won't attempt to locate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo: you want $e^{-1/x^2}$. With that in mind:

You should prove that for $n \geq 0$ and $x \neq 0$, you have $f^{(n)}(x) = p_n(x) f(x)$ for some rational function $p_n$. For example, $f'(x) = e^{-1/x^2} (2/x^3)$. Then $f$ is decaying faster than any polynomial in $x$ as $x \to 0$. Hence $f^{(n+1)}(0) = 0$.